# Char array seems to be overriding other data

Tags: c, x86-16, inline-assembly, bootloader

So I have another piece of code here which utilize the printchar function I wrote earlier:

```
void prints(char input[],int length){
 for (int i=1;i<=length;i++){
       printchar(input[i]);
  }
}
```

And it printed the boot sector of my os instead of input.

So I tried to create an array:

```
char test[]="TEST";
```

and print the individual letter with printchar():

and as expected, it printed the boot sector again. If I replace the array with regular char, it print the value of char.
Also, I'm pretty sure my printchar() function is working properly, because if I give it a letter to print, it print the letter, just as expected.

Here is my printchar function:

```
void printc(char in){
    asm volatile("mov ah,0x0e\n"
         "mov al,%0\n"
         "int 0x10\n"
         "mov al,0\n"
    ::"r"(in)
    :"eax","ax"
    ); 
}
```

Comment: `for (int i=1,i<=length,i++)` is invalid syntax unless `for` is defined as a macro.

Comment: I suspect the commas are a copying error, otherwise it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I suspect you're not giving a correct length when you call `prints`, so you're printing beyond the end of the string.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. The problem is most likely with how you're calling the function.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I always write , instead of ;

Comment: Use a debugger to examine memory at runtime.  BOCHS is good.  This isn't a [mcve] of your problem.  The inline asm should be fine, and you're just calling it with a simple loop.  Since you have an explicit length, starting at `1` means you can't miss the `0` terminator of an empty implicit length string or something.

Comment: I tried to mess with the DS register, and the prints function printed something different. Still cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a C problem, not an assembly problem. Arrays start at 0, not 1, and use semicolons, not commas, so `for (int i=1,i<=length,i++){` should be `for (int i=0;i<length;i++){`.

Comment: `for (int i=0,i<length,i++){` is also invalid. It should be `for (int i=0;i<length;i++){`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Whoops, missed that. Fixed now.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's printing the boot sector. It should just skip the first character.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are working with boot environment, are you sure your stack is set up correctly(after jumping to 32-bit) ?

Just to be sure, check all segment registers are set up correctly.

Also if you are in 32-bit mode, you can't(shouldn't) print using the bios int.
And how do you know it printed the bootsector exactly?

Comment: My operating system is based on real mode, so I can use bios interrupts.

Comment: Just check that the data is ok and accessible from inside the array. Do some if checks to make sure all characters are in the desired position first...

Comment: btw the linker actually complains:relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.rodata' if I don't give any options.